# Substitution in the Heston Solution, Jim Gatheral's The Volatility Surface

Tags: calculus, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have been having some issues with proving a result seen in Jim Gatheral's book The Volatility Surfrace. Specifically, in chapter 2 section "The Solution for European Options" he states the following:

$-\frac{\partial C}{\partial \tau} + \frac{1}{2} v C_{11} - \frac{1}{2} \eta^2 v C_{22} + \rho \eta v C_{12} - \lambda (v - \bar{v})C_{2} = 0 \quad (2.4)$

Where:

$\tau = T-t$

$x := log(F_{t,T}/K)$

$F_{t,T} = S_{0}e^{\int_t^T \mu_t dt}$

And the subscripts 1 and 2 represent differentiation with respect to $x$ and $v$ respectively. $\mu_t$ represents the risk-neutral drift of the stock price process.

We are then told that the solution to (2.4) has the form:

$C(x,v,\tau) = K [e^{x}P_{1}(x,v,\tau) - P_{0}(x,v,\tau)] \quad (2.5)$

Finally we are told that substitution of (2.5) into (2.4) gives:

$-\frac{\partial P_{j}}{\partial \tau} + \frac{1}{2} v \frac{\partial^2 P_{j}}{\partial x^2} - \big (\frac{1}{2} - j) v \frac{\partial P_{j}}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2} \eta^2 v \frac{\partial^2 P_{j}}{\partial v^2} + \rho \eta v \frac{\partial^2 P_{j}}{\partial x \partial v} + (a-b_j v)\frac{\partial P_{j}}{\partial v} = 0 \quad (2.6)$

Where:

$ a = \lambda \bar{v} $

$ b_{j} = \lambda - j \rho \eta $

It seems like in order to substitute (2.5) into (2.4) to achieve (2.6) we simply need to take the required derivatives of (2.5). However, when I do so I am unable to achieve the answer seen in (2.6).

I was wondering if anyone had some working to show how the result in (2.6) can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Are you missing the term $-\frac{1}{2} v C_1$ in $(2.4)$? The correct equations:
$$
\tag{2.7}
- \frac{\partial C}{\partial \tau} + \frac{1}{2} v C_{11} - \frac{1}{2} v C_1 + \frac{1}{2} \eta^2 v C_{22} + \rho \eta v C_{12} - \lambda (v - \bar{v})C_2 = 0
$$

By the chain rule, we obtain the followings:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial \tau}
&= Ke^x\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial \tau} - K\frac{\partial P_0}{\partial \tau}, \\
C_1
&= Ke^xP_1 + Ke^x\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial x} - K \frac{\partial P_0}{\partial x}, \\
C_{11}
&= \frac{\partial C_1}{\partial x}
= Ke^xP_1 + 2Ke^x\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial x} + Ke^x\frac{\partial^2 P_1}{\partial x^2} - K\frac{\partial^2 P_0}{\partial x^2}, \\
C_2
&= Ke^x\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial v} - K\frac{\partial P_0}{\partial v}, \\
C_{22}
&= \frac{\partial C_2}{\partial v}
= Ke^x\frac{\partial^2 P_1}{\partial v^2} - K\frac{\partial^2 P_0}{\partial v^2}, \\
C_{12}
&= \frac{\partial C_1}{\partial v} 
= Ke^x\frac{\partial P_1}{\partial v} + Ke^x\frac{\partial^2 P_1}{\partial x \partial v}- K\frac{\partial^2 P_0}{\partial x \partial v}.
\end{align}

By dividing these equations into the cases $j=0$ and $j=1$ and substituting them into $(2.7)$, we obtain the two equations (2.6).

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. Two quick follow up questions: Firstly, isn't $F_{t,T}$ a function to $\tau$. As such should it not appear somehow in $\frac{\partial C}{\partial \tau}$? Secondly, the equation (2.7) would include a summation of both the $P_0$ and $P_1$ terms. I'm sure this is a silly question but how come we can split (2.6) into separate equations, one for $P_{0}$ and one for $P_1$?

Comment: First question: $F_{t, T}$ is not a function of one variable $\tau (= T-t)$, but two variables $t$ and $T$. Indeed, it's defined as $F_{t, T} = S_t \mathrm{exp} \left\{ \int_t^T ds \mu_s \right\}$ in p.13. If it's a function of $\tau$, It would be written as $F_{T-t}$ or $F_{\tau}$.

Second question: Sorry, I can't give a rigorous explanation. I split $(2.6)$ (and also $(2.5)$) by analogy of the Black-Scholes case. If the option is in-the-money, $P_1 = 0$ and otherwise $P_0 = 0$. You can find a similar and easy explanation in pp.4-10 in "The Heston Model and its Extensions in MATLAB and C#".